# The Koszul complex is invariant

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am studying Koszul complex over a commutative noetherian local ring. I see the following propertie: If $I$ is an ideal, $x=x_1,\dots
,x_n$ and $y=y_1,\dots,y_n$ are minimal system of generators of $I$, then $K_{\bullet}(x)$ and $K_{\bullet}(y)$ are isomorphic. I'm trying to study the following proof:

[image]

Why is the matrix $A$ inversible?

Answer (score 3):

If we work modulo $\mathfrak m$ we get that the matrix $A$ is invertible modulo $\mathfrak m$, that is, $\det A\notin\mathfrak m$. This implies that $\det A$ is invertible in $R$ and so is the matrix $A$ in $M_n(R)$.